# Display Notifications in SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using Sugar Pro 6.4.0 and want to display a notification to a user in sugar's notification area present in menu bar as shown in the image below:

[image]

How I can add a notification in a way that notification counter gets incremented automatically and when user click on the sugar cube icon, the notification gets displayed as shown in the above image.

I want to display my own created message in notification window show above eg message like "CRON is in process..." in Notifications window shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have accomplished this task in a non upgrade safe way by updating the file:

> modules/Administration/DisplayWarnings.php

I have added the following code near the end of file

```
// Display Notification
displayAdminError("My notification message goes here...");
```

and it displays the message in notification area perfectly.

If anyone knows an upgrade safe way of accomplishing this task kindly let me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to set the Email settings, configure the Smtp server , username , password and you can use scheduler for this to send the email notification or you can use logic hooks

Comment: I think i have not explained my question. Actually i dont want to send an email. I want to display my own created message in notification window show above eg message like "CRON is in process" in Notifications window shown above. Anyway thankx for your help.